# EF Migration script to exit migration on a condition

Tags: entity-framework

I want to abort the migration in code first approach on a condition basis.

Suppose, if the condition is true, I want to exit the migration without making changes to the database.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with [MigrationBuilder.Sql(String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.sql?view=efcore-6.0) method, so create an SQL script with what you want to do with `IF...ELSE` conditions. Then create an empty migration and write the script in the `Sql()` method as a [verbatim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) string.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sales INT;

        SELECT 
            @sales = SUM(list_price * quantity)
        FROM
            sales.order_items i
            INNER JOIN sales.orders o ON o.order_id = i.order_id
        WHERE
            YEAR(order_date) = 2018;

        SELECT @sales;

        IF @sales > 1000000
        BEGIN
            -- // What you want to do if sales > 1,000,000
        END
    END
    ");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    // But you need to write another script to revert the changes done by Up method.
}
```

If you don't know how to create a script for your migration, use [Script-Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#script-migration).

I don't think you can run queries or inject services to migrations, since the Entity-framework command-line tool analyzes your code but does not run the startup.cs class.